# ExtJS DateField confuse format

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, extjs, date-format

I use Ext.form.DateField with specified format is 'd-m-Y', like this:

```
var sellingDate = new Ext.form.DateField({
    fieldLabel : "Selling date",
    width : 180,
    name: 'sellingDate',
    format: 'd-m-Y',
    allowBlank : false
});
```

I want this component to complete the input value automatically with given format after it lost focus. I mean if I input the text '040212' (**February 4th 2012**, in my country we use 'dd-mm-YYYY' as standard date format), it must display that text as '04-02-2012'.
But when debugging at event "change" of DateField, I see that the parsed Date object is "Mon **Apr 02 2012**". I don't know how to make it work as I expect above. Is there any way to get the raw text from date field, not a parsed Date object? Could you please help me on this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

That's simple, add the altFormats config option:

> altFormats : String Multiple date formats separated by "|" to try when
>   parsing a user input value and it does not match the defined format

```
//So in your case, it should be 'dmy'
var sellingDate = new Ext.form.DateField({
    fieldLabel : "Selling date",
    width : 180,
    name: 'sellingDate',
    format: 'd-m-Y',
    altFormats: 'dmy',
    allowBlank : false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ext parses any six-digit string as `mmddyy` regardless of the format you specify. That's unfortunate :-/

The logic for parsing the date occurs in the `beforeBlur` method of `Ext.form.field.Date` or (`Ext.form.DateField` in ExtJS 3). You can "intercept" that method and perform your own massaging of the raw value before it parses the date:

```
Ext.onReady(function (){
  (function (){

    // capture the original method so we can call it later
    var originalBeforeBlur = Ext.form.field.Date.prototype.beforeBlur;

    Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Date, {
      beforeBlur: function (){
        var raw = this.getRawValue(),
            match = raw.match(/^\s*(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\s*$/);

        // rearrange the date string to match what Ext expects
        if (match){
          raw = match[2] + match[1] + match[3];
        }

        this.setRawValue(raw);
        originalBeforeBlur.call(this);
      }
    });
  })();

  var panel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: "Enter a Date",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: {
      xtype: "datefield",
      format: "d-m-Y"
    }
  });
});
```